# Loomis head construction from extreme angles

Tags: drawing, sketching, portrait-drawing

I am practising the head construction based on Loomis method but finding it difficult to draw the extreme angles, and the neck placement on them, so, I haven't moved to the facial features yet. I have bought Loomis's book “Drawing head and hands" and have been reading it. However, this book doesn't provide most of the drawing of extreme angles of head along with the neck placement. It also doesn't provide the clear drawings with facial features on them. How can I draw them in easier way with necks and how can I draw the facial features even on those extreme angles of heads ?

Comment: Hi yubraj, it's still a bit unclear to me what exactly you're looking for. Can you add an image to your question of an example of the extreme angle you're looking for?

Comment: @Joachim Yes, I am looking for references for drawing extreme angles with features placed on them so that It gets easier to study and practice them , especially neck and jaw placement, and features ( angles of eyes, noses, ears) on them. I tried to break down some reference photos of my own into Loomis construction but I found difficult in those things

Comment: I also said that this books didn't provid something which I felt the need: references with neck and features placement in those construction correctly, the book doesn't seem to talk more on these subjects. Next, I tried to break down some extreme angles photos into Loomis head construction, but, to whom can I show and get checked out so that I can find my mistakes on them and make corrections.

Comment: But do you have an example of an extreme angle you'd like to be able to draw, so we can work from that specific example?

Comment: Sure, but not only one example will work ! There are plenty of angles!

Comment: Yes, but we can't show you how to do every single angle. If your provide one example, we can use that to figure out where your problem lies, and how to construct such an angle using the desired method.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question adding some examples with reference images too

Comment: Please do, yubraj.

Comment: I will do it soon, as I am collecting some references

Comment: Isn't this basically an extension of a question you already asked?  [Planes of the head](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/planes-of-the-head)  Sure, you added extreme angles, but the question at the core is essentially the same: "How do understand and use the Loomis method of drawing a head?"